# how to write following pattern in vim?

Tags: search, replace

I am sorry for the rather fuzzy title of my question. I am working on some text, which I take from web-page and try to annotate it with LaTeX commands using Vim.

How can I write in Vim following pattern:

```
dot line-break 2spaces capital letter
```

I have to search through the text to replace it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a dot followed by a new line beginning with two spaces and one capital letter you can use

```
\.\n\s\{2}[A-Z]
```

Where:

```
\.        Matches a literal .
\n        is a new line
\s        is a whitespace
\{2}      is exactly 2 occurences of the previous atom (i.e. \s)
[A-Z]     is a capital letter between A and Z
```

Comment: Slightly shorter with `\u` instead of `[A-Z]`, e.g. `\.\n\s\{2}\u`